# Origin of Compactness

Tags: mathematics, topology

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Urysohn, Urysohn and Alexandrov first formulated the modern definition of compactness. In which paper did they do this? Is there an English translation? If so, where can I find it?

Comment: See [*A pedagogical history of compactness*](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M365C/Compactness.pdf) by Manya Raman-Sundstrom (2015) ***AND*** [*La genèse du théorème de recouvrement de Borel*](http://www.numdam.org/article/RHM_2005__11_2_163_0.pdf) by Bernard Maurey and Jean-Pierre Tacchi (2005) ***AND*** [*The Borel theorem and its generalizations*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183487130) by Hildebrandt (1926).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See Wiki's entry on [Compact space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#References) :

> Alexandrov, Pavel and Urysohn, Pavel (1929), "Mémoire sur les espaces topologiques compacts", *Koninklijke Nederlandse Akademie van Wetenschappen te Amsterdam*, Proceedings of the section of mathematical sciences, 14.